# Is there any way to find number of prepositions in a given text using python?

Tags: python

There are many prepositions in English language. But how can I count number of prepositions in a text? Please help me

Comment: Have you tried the string method `find()`?

Comment: Yes but it returns only index of first occurance

Comment: please include any try if you had

Answer (score 1):

you can use the nltk tokenizer to accomplish that

here's a small example I tested for you

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk import word_tokenize

text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")

count = 0
for x,y in nltk.pos_tag(text):
    if y == "IN": count += 1

print(count)
```

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `spacy` library that does nlp (natural language processing).

You can look at their website to see how it works.

And to count the number of preposition you can access each tokens part of speech and only count the one that are PP (prepositions).

Something like:

```
# Download the english model
# python -m spacy download en
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp('your text')
print(sum(token.pos_ == 'ADP' for token in doc))
```

Some example for the pos are available [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features)